# How do those event registrations differ?

Tags: c#

I've now found both ways of registring eventhandlers several times.

What's the difference?

```
public delegate void SomeEventHandler();

public class SomeClass
{
    public event SomeEventHandler SomeEvent;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var sc1 = new SomeClass();
    sc1.SomeEvent += new SomeEventHandler(a_SomeEventHandler);

    var sc2 = new SomeClass();
    sc2.SomeEvent += a_SomeEventHandler;
}
```

Comment: no difference in short, in second compiler infers event type

Comment: @EhsanSajjad So it might be that one is just converted into the other at compiletime?

Comment: What is `a_SomeEventHandler`? a method? If yes, second one uses delegate type inference.

Comment: If `a_SomeEventHandler` defined as `Action a_SomeEventHandler;`, then second case will produce compile error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Short Answer:

There is no difference.

### Explanation:

In the first case we are explicitly telling the EventHandler type while in the second case compiler infers the type of delegate.

If you have Resharper installed, Visual Studio will fade out the line `sc1.SomeEvent += new SomeEventHandler(a_SomeEventHandler);` in first case saying **"Redudant explicit delegate creation"**

Answer (score 0):

Second one came just for coding efficiency to programmers. They give identical compiled result.

Compiler can inference second one as a first old (or explicit we can say) style, as `SomeEvent` only can accept the way of first one.

Answer (score 0):

The first syntax was the only one in the very first versions of C#. The second, shorter syntax was introduced later in the language.

As explained in the other answers it serves exactly the same purpose. There is no difference at all.